# Locate & Open File - Using Python

Tags: python, search

For example, if I was to have it search and find a file named ex.exe, it should then prompt whether you'd like to open the file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me you can check it out if it works for you too.

```
import os

def find_files(filename, search_path):
    result = []

    # Wlaking top-down from the root
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path):
        if filename in files:
            result.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return result
find_files("sample.pdf", "E:\\")
```

If you want to look for folders you can try this worked perfectly for me.

```
import os
start = "E:\\"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start):
    if "dev" in dirnames :
        print(dirnames)
```

To execute an exe file you can use the below methods:

```
import os
path = "C:/"
os.chdir(path)
os.system("example.exe")
```

Comment: what error did you got? or are you by any chance looking for folder?

Comment: It just doesn't come up with any results.

Comment: try the code that i have  added in mine i believe you were trying to find a folder. and by the way this is just for locating folders and files the code tthat i have shared with you

Answer (score 0):

You can import os
then with the help of
os.system("*pass any windows cmd here*")
like regular file search make it happen

Comment: So how would that be written out exactly? I'm not quite sure I understand; sorry, I'm new with Python.